# 2D spherical wave projection generator not working properly

Tags: java, math

I made an algorithm that makes a 2d wave assigning at each point a value.

The linear wave generator works fine, but the circular wave is not generated properly.

The algorithm is based on for loops that works one inside the other, operating respectively on the distance from the center and on the angle, then it generates the value for each coordinate using trigonometric functions.

I think the problem is the low accuracy of the algorithm, particularly the angle. But if I want to increase this accuracy, I'm slowing down the algorithm a lot. If so, can you provide me another algorithm.

By the way, here's the code:

```
//f is the frequency, phase is the phase, x and y are the source coordinates
public void addCircularWave(double f, double phase, int x, int y){
    //field is the 2d array which will store the sum of all the waves
    int w = field.length;
    int h = field[0].length;

    double[][] wave = new double[w][h];

    //max finds the maximum value in the arguments
    double maxd = max(abs(w - x), abs(h - y));

    //main algorithm
    for(int dist = 0; dist < maxd; dist++){
        //i think here there is the problem
        //particularly "theta += 2*PI/720"
        //because as the distance increases it becomes less accurate.
        for(double theta = 0; theta < 2*PI; theta += 2*PI/720){
            int x0 = (int)(dist*sin(theta) + x);
            int y0 = (int)(dist*cos(theta) + y);

            //arrayoutofbounds prevention
            if(y0 < h && x0 < w && x0 > 0 && y0 > 0){
                wave[x0][y0] = sin(f*dist + phase);
            }
        }
    }

    //here the wave it's put in a map, waiting to be processed.
    cache.put(wave, new double[]{f, 0, phase, 1, x, y});
}
```

I expect a clean-looking wave. So, can you help me with my algorithm, or can you give me another better algorithm.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is *way* over-complicated.

Remember that a circular wave is rotationally symmetric, i.e. there is no need to iterate over the angle; the amplitude **only** depends on the distance from the source (and of course the frequency / phase; it's assumed that you simulate time-dependence by varying the latter).

Just iterate over all of the grid cells, and calculate their distance to the source:

```
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        // calculate Euclidean distance to source
        double dx = i - x, dy = j - y;
        double dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        // no need to check bounds explicitly here
        wave[i][j] = Math.sin(f * dist + phase);
    }
}
```

Side note:

- It would be more appropriate to rename "frequency" to **wave vector** (this won't change the code however).
- Unlike linear waves, circular waves [decay with distance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326317/does-a-circular-surface-water-wave-decrease-by-2-pir) due to energy conservation.

Comment: Thank you. I did a similar thing for the linear wave code, but I didn't know how to do it for circular wave, so I complicated my code.